# JPA/Hibernate primary key value sequence using current year

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa-2.0

I am using Spring 3 and Hibernate 4

I have the following in Entity class

```
    @Id
    @Column(name = "PROJECT_NO")
    private String projectNumber;
```

When I insert values into database table, is it possible to insert `PROJECT_NO` value which is the Primary key in the following format

`20131` where 2013 is the current year and next character should be incremental by one. i.e. next value to be inserted should be `20132`

How can I achieve this using JPA/Hibernate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to look at [@GeneratedValue](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/GeneratedValue.html) and [@GenericGenerator](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/annotations/GenericGenerator.html) annotation.

There are several possibilities to generate value. In your case I believe the you need to create something like the following:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "year_gen")
@GenericGenerator(name = "year_gen", strategy = "com.example.generator.CustomGenerator")
@Column(name = "PROJECT_NO")
private String projectNumber;
```

And `CustomGenerator` should implement `org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerator`

Comment: I will try this approach of a class in strategy. Thanks n1ckolas

Comment: And after you've tried it and (if) it works, be sure to check this as the answer!

Comment: @n1ckolas Give some time, I haven't tried this. Once I will try I will let you know. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What about putting the JPA annotation on the getter and using the getter method to format the data as you like?

```
@Entity
public class MyClass {
 private String projectNumber;

 @Column(name = "PROJECT_NO")
 public String getProjectNumber(){
  return doSomeFormatting(this.projectNumber);
 }
}
```

Something like that should work.